# how to build data field in the solana instruction manually?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi

```
let inst = Instruction::new_with_borsh(
            ctx.accounts.dest_pm.key(),
            &data,
            account_metas,
        );

 invoke(&inst, &vec![ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info()]);
```

In the above instruction, How to build data field manually ?

```
#[derive(Debug, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Intialize{}

let mut function_identifier: Vec<u8> = vec![175,175,109,31,13,152,155,237];
let instruction = Intialize{};
let mut x = instruction.try_to_vec().unwrap();
let mut data = function_identifier.clone();
data.append(&mut x);
```

This is the process I have followed, 
function_identifier -> I took it from the explorer instruction_data
instruction -> It is a struct that has program-A function name
data -> This the final argument that is passed to construct instruction

```
 pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("CPI is succesful with unchecked account as program address");
        Ok(())
    }
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}
```

The above code snippet is Program-A code, Which is being invoked by Program-B.
By following this method, I am getting following error -

> Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound.
> Error Number: 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not
> supported.

Comment: This is the correct thing to do. Be sure that there's no other data required in the instruction, that the function identifier is correct, and that the program is correct. Otherwise, you've got it completely right!